# Searching pdf files with php

Tags: php, pdf

I have a website in which the contents are mainly pdf. Is there a possible way to search through them when the user enters a keyword from a form then dispay the pdf files that have that key word in them

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PDF2php](http://pastebin.com/hRviHKp1) to get the text from the PDFs.

Example:

```
$pdf = new PDF2Text();
$pdf->setFilename('pdffile.pdf'); //select the pdf
$pdf->decodePDF(); //process the pdf
echo $pdf->output(); //output the text from the PDF
```

---

If you want to search by words you could create an index in database using a table whith columns `word` and `pdf` and populate it with the words readed from the files and their location on the server. That you don't have to scan all the files for each request, just query the database.

Similar solutions can be created or other types of search.

Comment: Thanks let me try it out